# Set column width to content length in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I looked at the documentation but did not find such property.
I want to fit all cells in one column to its content width using css grid.

For the first case I should apply this property for the container: `grid-template-columns: auto auto;`

But what should I do for the second case?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `grid-template-columns: min-content auto`?

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks, it worked for me! :) Very strange that there is no info about this prop in many css grid guides...

Comment: `min-content` will wrap any text after white space, so `white-space: nowrap;` can be used as a fix

Comment: @besthost it's possible to use `max-content` to prevent wrapping

Answer (score 136):

To make *all* columns "shrink-to-fit", use an inline-level grid container:

```css
article {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
article { background-color: black; border: 1px solid black; }
section { background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<article>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>cell3</section>
  <section>cell4</section>
</article>
```

To make *one* column "shrink-to-fit", use `min-content`:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
article { background-color: black; border: 1px solid black; }
section { background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<article>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>cell3</section>
  <section>cell4</section>
</article>
```

But `auto` with `1fr` would also work because the `fr` would consume all free space on the line, collapsing the other column as much as possible:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
article { background-color: black; border: 1px solid black; }
section { background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<article>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>cell3</section>
  <section>cell4</section>
</article>
```

More info in the spec:

- [7.2. Explicit Track Sizing: the `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)

Comment: This `grid-template-columns: auto max-content;` worked for me.

Answer (score 30):

Set the following on the grid container:

```
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
```

This sets the width of the **first column** to equal the width of the widest item in that column, and the width of the **second column** to get the remaining width of the grid.

To right-align the content of the second column we can simply use `text-align: right`

```
span:nth-child(2n) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span:nth-child(2n) {
  text-align: right;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige; /* colors for demo */
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: wheat;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>some content here</span>
  <span>content</span>
  <span>cell3</span>
  <span>cell4</span>
</div>
```

**NB:** Setting column widths with `min-content` is a little more aggressive :) and will set the width of the column to the width of the **largest word** in the column.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}
span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span:nth-child(2n) {
  text-align: right;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: wheat;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>some content here</span>
  <span>content</span>
  <span>cell3</span>
  <span>cell4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me (be it on rows).. Problem was that browser chose the min-content of the overlapping column next to it.

Comment: what if I want to apply that just to a cell? for example to span:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: beige;
}